# I want to learn how to select appropriate colors and fonts for a new site

Tags: color, typography, resource-recommendations

I'm developing a new site, and although I know enough basic programming to make the site, I'm not artistically inclined enough to make the site look nice. So, I was hoping I could get some suggestions or something on what colors and fonts go well together to make a nice looking website; only for the users experience.

So, does anyone have any suggestions, or sites that may help me learn about such a thing? I'm really just developing a basic site, so it can be basic colors, just nothing to dark or light I guess. I'm thinking somewhere in the middle.

Comment: find a site you like and study the colors and typefaces it uses.

Comment: Yeah true, that is one way to go, yet I don't want to end up copying the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question covers two distinct areas of design: color theory and typography.  Color theory covers why blue text on a red background may not be a good idea.  Typography covers the style, usage and spacing of fonts or the letters on the page.

In addition to the links @Luuk provide, you may want to take a look at these:

Typography:

[10 Rules Every Designer Should Know](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2009/02/10-web-typography-rules-every-designer-should-know-2/) - from Webdesigner Depot

[A Guide To Web Typography](http://ilovetypography.com/2008/02/28/a-guide-to-web-typography/) - from I Love Typography

Color Theory:

[Colors in Web Design](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/colors-web-design-right-combination/) - 1stWebDesigner

[Color Theory For Designers - Part 1](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/28/color-theory-for-designers-part-1-the-meaning-of-color/) - from Smashing Magazine

[Color Theory For Designers - Part 2](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/02/color-theory-for-designers-part-2-understanding-concepts-and-terminology/)

[Color Theory For Designers - Part 3](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/08/color-theory-for-designer-part-3-creating-your-own-color-palettes/)

I had the links handy because I refer to them often.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You may also find this tool helpful: http://kuler.adobe.com

Answer (score 1):

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com and http://www.smashingmagazine.com should give you a good starts. Just browse through the articles. In fact... Article 2 on tutsplus is already about typography.

hope this helps you